# How do I continue on with the current sum in a Calculator program made using Swing?

Tags: java

```
 class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

public static Font jtfont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30);
JCheckBox checkbox;
JButton jb1, jb2, jb3, jb4, jb5;
JTextField t1, t2;
JTextArea textarea;

boolean a;
double factor1, factor2, factor3, sum;
Test() {
    
    Font jtfont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30);
    Font ta = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20);

    
    textarea = new JTextArea();
    textarea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,60));
    textarea.setFont(ta);
    textarea.setText(" Input the first number below and \n the second number below that");
    textarea.setEditable(false);
    add(textarea);
    
    t1 = new JTextField();
    t1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));
    t1.setFont(jtfont);
    add(t1);

    t2 = new JTextField();
    t2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,50));
    t2.setFont(jtfont);
    add(t2);

    jb1 = new JButton("+");
    jb1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,40));
    add(jb1);
    
    jb2 = new JButton("-");
    jb2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,40));
    add(jb2);

    jb3 = new JButton("*");
    jb3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,40));
    add(jb3);

    jb4 = new JButton("/");
    jb4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,40));
    add(jb4);
    
    checkbox = new JCheckBox();
    checkbox.setText("Continue with the current product");
    checkbox.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    
    jb5 = new JButton("Submit");
    jb5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,40));
    
    jb1.addActionListener(this);
    jb2.addActionListener(this);
    jb3.addActionListener(this);
    jb4.addActionListener(this);
    jb5.addActionListener(this);
    checkbox.addActionListener(this);


    this.setTitle("Calculator"); //title
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //exit
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(36, 36, 36)); 
    this.setSize(325,400); //x and y dimension
    this.setVisible(true); //this visibility
    this.setResizable(false);
    }


    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    factor1 = Float.parseFloat(t1.getText());
    factor2 = Float.parseFloat(t2.getText());
    sum = 0;
  
    if (e.getSource() == jb1) {
        sum = factor1 + factor2;
        textarea.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        add(checkbox);
        add(jb5);

    } else if (e.getSource() == jb2) {
        sum = factor1 - factor2;
        textarea.setFont(jtfont);
        textarea.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        add(checkbox);
        add(jb5);

    } else if (e.getSource() == jb3) {
        sum = factor1 * factor2;
        textarea.setFont(jtfont);
        textarea.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        add(checkbox);
        add(jb5);

    } else if (e.getSource() == jb4) {
        sum = factor1 / factor2;
        textarea.setFont(jtfont);
        textarea.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        add(checkbox);
        add(jb5);
    } 
    
    if (e.getSource() == jb5) {
        a = checkbox.isSelected(); }
    
    if (a == true) {
      
        if (e.getSource() == jb1) {
            factor3 = Float.parseFloat(t2.getText());
            sum = Float.parseFloat(textarea.getText());
            textarea.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

            

        } else if (e.getSource() == jb2) {
            factor1 = factor1 - factor2;
            textarea.setFont(jtfont);
            textarea.setText(String.valueOf(factor1));
            

        } else if (e.getSource() == jb3) {
            factor1 = factor1 * factor2;
            textarea.setFont(jtfont);
            textarea.setText(String.valueOf(factor1));
            

        } else if (e.getSource() == jb4) {
            factor1 = factor1 / factor2;
            textarea.setFont(jtfont);
            textarea.setText(String.valueOf(factor1));
            
        } 
        
    }
    
}// end actionPerformed

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Test t = new Test();
}
    }
```

Whenever I try to continue on with the previous sum after ticking the checkbox and clicking submit  the calculations get messed up. It looks like that it is still adding the numbers from t1 and t2 together even though it isn't supposed to. I also noticed that everytime I click a button the if blocks ran again by themselves. Maybe it is getting messed up cuz of that, I'm still not entirely sure since I am a beginner in Java and don't know anything about Swing.

Comment: Whenever the user clicks on any of the buttons, method `actionPerformed` is executed. That's why _everytime I click a button the if blocks ran again by themselves_ Put a breakpoint in method `actionPerformed` and run your code using the debugger of your IDE and see how that method changes the contents of `textarea`.

Comment: 1) *"How do I continue on with the current sum in a Calculator program made using Swing?"* The same way you would in a JavaFX app., a servlet or a console app. I.E. this has nothing to do with Swing. But since you've put that code up.. 2) `new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30);` should be `new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 30);` to get a sans-serif font reliably on systems that don't install Arial. In fact, the users of Mac OS will get the font they prefer - Helvetica. 3) `t1 = new JTextField();` should be something like `t1 = new JTextField(20);` for a number of columns and ..

Comment: .. `setPreferredSize` should not be used as it is no better than a guess. Even if it happens to be right on one PC, it will be wrong on others. Leave it to the layouts which can size the component according to the natural preferred size. 4) `this.setSize(325,400);` another guess. Get the correct size by calling `this.pack();`, but do so after calling `this.setResizable(false);` & before calling 'this.setVisible(true);`